# Why my second Google Maps div overlapping Text

Tags: html, css

wanna ask something, I created a landing page for invitations, I need 2 google maps location div. The first one was okay the position was correct. But the second one is overlapping text. This is my screenshot:

[image: overlap]

Here's my code :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="text-center text-md-left ml-md-3">
                        <h4 class="mb-3">Holy Matrimony</h4>
                        <p class="mb-2">Gereja HKBP Jatiwaringin, Jakarta Timur</p></p>
                        <p class="mb-0">14:30PM - 15:30PM</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="wrapper-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3">
        <div id="map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3"></div><script>(function () {
        var setting = {"height":260,"width":310,"zoom":16,"queryString":"Gereja HKBP Jatiwaringin, RT.7/RW.6, Cipinang Melayu, East Jakarta City, Jakarta, Indonesia","place_id":"ChIJJTtA-tOMaS4RQ2QWfy6gFoY","satellite":false,"centerCoord":[-6.2502256017392215,106.91757155],"cid":"0x8616a02e7f166443","lang":"en","cityUrl":"/indonesia/jakarta","cityAnchorText":"Map of Jakarta, Java, Indonesia","id":"map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3","embed_id":"898388"};
        var d = document;
        var s = d.createElement('script');
        s.src = 'https://1map.com/js/script-for-user.js?embed_id=898388';
        s.async = true;
        s.onload = function (e) {
          window.OneMap.initMap(setting)
        };
        var to = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        to.parentNode.insertBefore(s, to);
      })();</script><a href="https://1map.com/map-embed">1 Map</a></div>
      <br>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="text-center text-md-left ml-md-3">
                        <h4 class="mb-3">The Reception</h4>
                        <p class="mb-2">Rhema Convention Hall, Bekasi</p>
                        <p class="mb-0">19:00PM - 21:00PM</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="wrapper-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3">
        <div id="map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3"></div><script>(function () {
        var setting = {"height":260,"width":310,"zoom":16,"queryString":"Rhema Convention Hall, Jakasampurna, Bekasi City, West Java, Indonesia","place_id":"ChIJtRGzWf-MaS4RsIECDJBz_e0","satellite":false,"centerCoord":[-6.249366001739006,106.95926959999998],"cid":"0xedfd73900c0281b0","lang":"en","cityUrl":"/indonesia/jakarta","cityAnchorText":"Map of Jakarta, Java, Indonesia","id":"map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3","embed_id":"898388"};
        var d = document;
        var s = d.createElement('script');
        s.src = 'https://1map.com/js/script-for-user.js?embed_id=898388';
        s.async = true;
        s.onload = function (e) {
          window.OneMap.initMap(setting)
        };
        var to = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        to.parentNode.insertBefore(s, to);
      })();</script><a href="https://1map.com/map-embed">1 Map</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Try to locate the embed code in different position and andded 
 but it still overlapping..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use multiple `id` in your HTML. The HTML `id` attribute should be unique, so you just change the second map element from:

```html
...
<div id="wrapper-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3">
<div id="map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3"></div>
...
"id": "map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3"
...
var to = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
...
```

to:

```html
...
<div id="wrapper-ch8fmmit9ybmd2v5w665hbqwr43gruny">
<div id="map-ch8fmmit9ybmd2v5w665hbqwr43gruny"></div>
...
"id": "map-ch8fmmit9ybmd2v5w665hbqwr43gruny"
...
var to = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[1];
...
```

---

Full code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="text-center text-md-left ml-md-3">
            <h4 class="mb-3">Holy Matrimony</h4>
            <p class="mb-2">Gereja HKBP Jatiwaringin, Jakarta Timur</p>
            <p class="mb-0">14:30PM - 15:30PM</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="wrapper-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3">
            <div id="map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3"></div>
            <script>
                (function() {
                    var setting = {
                        "height": 260,
                        "width": 310,
                        "zoom": 16,
                        "queryString": "Gereja HKBP Jatiwaringin, RT.7/RW.6, Cipinang Melayu, East Jakarta City, Jakarta, Indonesia",
                        "place_id": "ChIJJTtA-tOMaS4RQ2QWfy6gFoY",
                        "satellite": false,
                        "centerCoord": [-6.2502256017392215, 106.91757155],
                        "cid": "0x8616a02e7f166443",
                        "lang": "en",
                        "cityUrl": "/indonesia/jakarta",
                        "cityAnchorText": "Map of Jakarta, Java, Indonesia",
                        "id": "map-9cd199b9cc5410cd3b1ad21cab2e54d3",
                        "embed_id": "898388"
                    };
                    var d = document;
                    var s = d.createElement('script');
                    s.src = 'https://1map.com/js/script-for-user.js?embed_id=898388';
                    s.async = true;
                    s.onload = function(e) {
                        window.OneMap.initMap(setting)
                    };
                    var to = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    to.parentNode.insertBefore(s, to);
                })();
            </script><a href="https://1map.com/map-embed">1 Map</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="text-center text-md-left ml-md-3">
            <h4 class="mb-3">The Reception</h4>
            <p class="mb-2">Rhema Convention Hall, Bekasi</p>
            <p class="mb-0">19:00PM - 21:00PM</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="wrapper-ch8fmmit9ybmd2v5w665hbqwr43gruny">
            <div id="map-ch8fmmit9ybmd2v5w665hbqwr43gruny"></div>
            <script>
                (function() {
                    var setting = {
                        "height": 260,
                        "width": 310,
                        "zoom": 16,
                        "queryString": "Rhema Convention Hall, Jakasampurna, Bekasi City, West Java, Indonesia",
                        "place_id": "ChIJtRGzWf-MaS4RsIECDJBz_e0",
                        "satellite": false,
                        "centerCoord": [-6.249366001739006, 106.95926959999998],
                        "cid": "0xedfd73900c0281b0",
                        "lang": "en",
                        "cityUrl": "/indonesia/jakarta",
                        "cityAnchorText": "Map of Jakarta, Java, Indonesia",
                        "id": "map-ch8fmmit9ybmd2v5w665hbqwr43gruny",
                        "embed_id": "898388"
                    };
                    var d = document;
                    var s = d.createElement('script');
                    s.src = 'https://1map.com/js/script-for-user.js?embed_id=898388';
                    s.async = true;
                    s.onload = function(e) {
                        window.OneMap.initMap(setting)
                    };
                    var to = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    to.parentNode.insertBefore(s, to);
                })();
            </script><a href="https://1map.com/map-embed">1 Map</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mantap, sama-sama :)